# How to differentiate between sliding and clicking in android?

Tags: java, android

In pure Java there is `MouseInputListener` which I can use to work with those 2 events.

How do I do it with Android?

If I implement both events then only one is fired (`onClickListener`) and not the other.

**Updated:**

The question is not about detecting the finger movement.

I have a View (`ImageView` for example). I need to detect the click on this view which is `onClickListener()` and finger movement on this view (i.e. press, move then release the finger).

The problem here is that only `onClickListener()` is called and `MotionEvent` handler is not caught.

I need to be able to differentiate those 2 events as the main event should be finger movement and `onClickListener()` should just say "Don't click this view. Spin this view."

Hopefully this is more clear.

Comment: Relevant, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/937313/866022

Comment: You probably want to capture finger touches and `MotionEvent`, or were you looking specifically for capturing mouse input?

Answer (score 0):

`OnClickListener` and [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) kinda obstruct each other, since they both consume the `MotionEvent`s that get caught on the `View`.

Basically you can write a single `OnTouchListener` that checks for both things. You'll get supplied with the MotionEvent as an argument. Check it's action via `MotionEvent.getAction()`, e.g. if it equals `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` *(the user put the finger on the display)*. If the user releases the finger at approx. the same position *(`ACTION_UP`)*, you may want to interpret that as a click. Otherwise interpret the positions that you get with the `ACTION_MOVE` event as a gesture.

But the framework already has some classes that do this interpreting work for you, check out the [`SimpleGestureDetector`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) class and it's [`SimpleOnGestureListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html). That has some callbacks for common events, e.g. `onSingleTapConfirmed()` and `onFling()`. All you need to do is supply the MotionEvents from your OnTouchListener to the GestureDetector.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark this as the [correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was helpful. *(Since you are new to SO you may not be aware of that mechanism)*